# Creating static Datacontext() or Creating whenever its needed. Which is Better, and Why?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a function, and inside that I am creating a `DataContext()` everytime the function is called. What is the cost of creating a `new DataContext()`. Can I create a `static DataContext()` and use it everywhere. Because *The DataContext has a full recording of all the changes when SubmitChanges() fails*, is there a way I can remove those specific changes from the `DataContext` when `SubmitChanges()` fails. My Question is which is better `Creating static Datacontext()` or `Creating whenever its needed`?

Comment: Duplicatie http://stackoverflow.com/q/4081071/532498

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This topic has been discussed quite a bit and you should [read this article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management) about DataContext lifetime management. The short answer is that `DataContext` is meant to be used for a unit of work, typically a single request. DataContext objects are cheap to construct and there is no database overhead to creating one.

The main reason to avoid a shared instance of `DataContext` is because of thread safety and change tracking. Each modification you make to a repository object is captured and translated into update/insert/delete operations when you call `SubmitChanges()`. This feature breaks down when using a single `DataContext` object.

Comment: @BC: So if there are no update/insert/delete operations, i.e. if my application is Query Only, can I use the `static readonly DataContext()`

Comment: It's safe to say yes. Keep in mind that you can optimize different contexts for different purposes. For example, the `AssociateWith` load options. Sometimes, it can be helpful to specify multiple data contexts to support different load options. Also, if you aren't doing any Update/Insert/Delete ops you can turn off object tracking to boost performance. I think it's `ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.associatewith.aspx