# Datacontext reset at c#

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding

My WP app can edit data from database, which I get using LINQ query:

```
from item in db.SomeTable
where item.Id = 5
select new { Item = item}
```

And then I bind that selection to form controls.
When I don't want to save changes (no `db.SubmitChanges()` call), I call another LINQ to reset field, but I get changed source values from db (even when I'm using `select new {}` operator.
If there any way to reset to default state, so that I can get default values using LINQ again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same instance of the `DataContext`, you will get the latest version of any entities within it. You might want to consider changing your application to keep the `DataContext`s open for the minimum amount of time

Comment: You mean that I need to create new instance of DataContext on every page? Not global one for all app? I thought, that when I'm using `new` operator LINQ looses link with `DataContext`.

Comment: @Wayne `new` is there for projecting purposes, it has nothing to do with the database values

Comment: Your `new` is creating an object that *references the one from the `DataContext`* - you *could* call a copy constructor to read a copy of the current object, but then pushing edits back is going to be more work.

Comment: @Wayne - You should look into the following SO answer. Essentially it creates a single DataContext *per request*. You can tailor this to per page or even in a specific method if necessary. A global static DataContext will track changes across requests which is likely not what you're expecting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940912/linqtosql-static-datacontext-in-a-web-application